# Galaxy S 4: A custom OS can cause critical problems

Tags: hardware

today I restarted my cell and suddenly this message appeard when I turned it on.

[image]

I've already looked thought many forums and tried out different things to make it work. But nothing helped yet.

I got to know that it can happen if the volume button is jammed, but nothing changes even if I poke it with a knife.

I tried to start it in recovery mode, but it doesnt work. When I press volume up + home + power button the galaxy logo and then the samsung logo appear and cellphone runs in safe mode. There isn't any blue text at the top of the screen when its turning on. I don't know if its even able to run in recovery mode. And I have no idea what to do with it in safe mode.

I also shut it down and left it without battery for quite a while (some people claimed it helped). But still no success.

Does anyone have an idea what I can do else? Thanks in advance

**Add:** When I normally start then this warning appears. Each damn time. And the buttons don't work, i can't do anything. 
No, my cell doesn't work normally. It can only boot in safe mode and that's it.

Comment: Actually, it's the ODIN/Download mode. And what exactly happens when you normally start your phone, i.e without the combo buttons

Comment: Yep, this is called "Download mode" and is usually accessed with a device powered off by holding down Power, Home and volume down buttons. It's meant to be there, and if you aren't using the program Odin or Heimdall, or if you aren't sure what they are, then you can ignore it. Does your phone boot up normally now? Is it running?

Comment: Add: When I normally start then this warning appears. Each damn time. And the buttons don't work, i can't do anything. No, my cell doesn't work normally. It can only boot in safe mode and that's it.